# Como gravar uma váriavel std::vector<std::tuple<>> em um arquivo txt?

Tags: array, c++

Possuo o vector de tuplas escrito em C++, definido como:

```
std::vector<std::tuple< float, float>> ASK_Mod;
```

Populei ele, e tentei gravá-lo em um novo arquivo .txt como definido na função, porém, ele só funciona para vectors sem tuplas.

```
std::ofstream outfile("ASKModulation.txt");
outfile.open("ASKModulation.txt");


if(outfile.is_open())
{

    std::copy(ASK_ModulatedWave.rbegin(), ASK_ModulatedWave.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(outfile, "\n"));

}else
{
    std::cout << "ERROR! Could not export!" << std::endl;
}
outfile.close();
```

O erro que retorna é:

> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:324:18: error: no match for
>   ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream_iterator’ and
>   ‘std::tuple’)
>           *__result = *__first;

Como posso fazer para gravar a variável ASK_Mod em um arquivo .txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das coisas que precisam ser feitas é definir o operador << para o tipo que você quer jogar na stream. No seu caso, o operador << para std::tuple precisa ser definido.

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const std::tuple< float, float>& tp)
{
    const auto [p1, p2] = tp;
    os << p1;
    os << p2;
    return os;
}
```

Não consegui fazer funcionar com o std::copy, porém um loop resolve o seu problema.

```
std::for_each(ASK_Mod.rbegin(), ASK_Mod.rend(), [&](const std::tuple<float, float>& tp) {
    outfile << tp;
});
```

Link para solução compilando: https://godbolt.org/z/4ECSRK

Comment: Então, gostei do que você fez, porém o arquivo gerado fica vazio, e verifiquei se entra no loop que criaste, e entra, porém não grava aparentemente

Comment: @FourZeroFive O arquivo era aberto duas vezes, no construtor e no método open(). Isso fez com que o conteúdo não fosse escrito. Atualizei o link para uma solução funcionando :)

Comment: Muito agradecido, perfeito!